# email value passing as NULL

Tags: angular, typescript

create-employee.html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <span><input type="text" [required]="!standingQueue" class="form-control" name="exampleInputEmail1"
                [(ngModel)]="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"
                #email></span>
          </div>
```

create-employee.ts

```
async createEmployee() {

    var employee = {
      imageurl: (this.imageurl != null && this.imageurl != '') ? this.imageurl : null,
      id: (this.userid.trim() == "") ? "Null" : this.userid,
      name: (this.name.trim() == "") ? "Null" : this.name,
      email: (this.email.trim() == "") ? "Null" : this.email,
      employeeStoreId: (this.store != null && this.store != '') ? this.store : null,
      isAvailable: true,

    }

    let result = await this.api.CreateEmployee(employee);
    this.name = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.store = '';
    if (result) {
      this.router.navigate(['../admin/list-employee']);
    }
    console.log(employee)

async storelist() {
    this.rawlist = await this.api.ListStores();
    this.storelist = this.rawlist.items;
  }
  singUpToAWS(email: HTMLInputElement, contactNo: HTMLInputElement, username: HTMLInputElement, password: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.userName = username.value;
    const user = {
      username: username.value,
      password: "Maxis123",
      attributes: {
        email: email.value

      }
    }
    console.log(user)
```

So here I am trying to create employee along with sign up. But in create employee API I have a value name email and signup function also has email value. So as I know I can not have #email and [(ngModel)]="email" with the same name. Bcz "#email " is for element reference. Any helo

Comment: Rename your `[(ngModel)]="email"` to `[(ngModel)]="userEmail"` and access it in your ts file using `this.userEmail`. I'm not entirely sure but I think this is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your `[(ngModel)]="email"` to `[(ngModel)]="userEmail"` and access it in your ts file using `this.userEmail`.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding :)